# set default class Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very much new to Javascript and I could need a little help with the following problem:

I want to use the following function to make a header that closes and opens upon clicking it and I stumbled upon this function, in which I added the 'closed' class, which I would like to set as a default when the page is loaded initially. Does somebody have an idea for me, I would be very much grateful!

```
$(function() {
  var b = $("#contact");
  var w = $("#button");
  var l = $("#list");

  w.height(l.outerHeight(true));

  b.click(function() {

  if(w.hasClass('closed')) {
  w.removeClass('closed');
  w.addClass('open');
  w.height(l.outerHeight(true));
} else {
  w.addClass('closed');
  w.height(0);
}

  });
});
```

Comment: Why can't you just add the class to the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `$(…)` is called once when the page initially loads. You already use that to set up the click handler that toggles the `closed` class. So in addition to setting the click handler, you can also just add the class there:

```
$(function() {
  …
  b.click(function() {
    …
  });

  // set the initial class value
  w.addClass('closed');
});
```

Comment: don't you think that using the `class` attribute is better? I mean, he can later manipulate it using jQuery.

Comment: @weirdpanda I wouldn’t do this with jQuery at all, but in OP’s code, `w` is already a jQuery object. And yeah, you could just set the class attribute, but you don’t know if there aren’t any other class names on it, you would overwrite that way.

Comment: @poke: thank you, I added the initial class value and also changed `w.height(l.outerHeight(true));` right after the definition of the variables to `w.height(0);`, which I should have done in the first place. Sorry, my question was probably a little unnecessary